# How to get the control inside datatemplate of a combobox in silverlight4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a checkbox inside the data template of combobox in silverlight4. Now i want to get the checkbox in combobox on selectedindex changed event of it.So how i can do that ?

Here is my code :

```
 <ComboBox Height="Auto" x:Name="CB_Categories" SelectionChanged="CB_Categories_SelectionChanged" Tag="">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Content="{Binding Name}" CommandParameter="{Binding ProductCategoryID}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
```

Please Help me guys.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do so, you will probably be better off to just bind the checkbox property that you want to investigate or change, to a value in a background viewmodel or controller.

E.g. if it was the `IsChecked` that you want to change to true, then try this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Description}" />
```

You then hook up the `ComboBox` to a list of items using its `ItemsSource` property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Description}" />
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Also you will have to set the `DataContext` of the container control or the `ComboBox` so that the control can access the object with those properties.

Doing it this way, means you can have less code in the code-behind of the control or window that is just doing plumbing work like updating controls.

If you need more examples, let me know...